# Concat values of two dropdowns and show in input (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I have 2 dropdowns. Here is html code of component.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label>{{l("RoomType")}}</label>
     <p-dropdown [disabled] = "!roomTypes.length"  [options]="roomTypes" autoWidth="false"  [style]="{'width':'100%'}" name="roomTypes" [autoWidth]="true" [(ngModel)]="room.roomTypeId"></p-dropdown>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
        <label>{{l("RoomNumber")}}</label>
        <p-dropdown [disabled] = "!roomNumbers.length"  [options]="roomNumbers" autoWidth="false"  [style]="{'width':'100%'}" name="numberRoom" [autoWidth]="true" [(ngModel)]="room.roomNumber"></p-dropdown>
</div>
```

Here is how they populated in ts

```
getRoomTypes(): void {
    this._roomTypeService.getRoomTypesDropdownValues().subscribe(r => {
        r.items.forEach((value) => {
            this.roomTypes.push({label: value.name, value: value.id});
        });
    });
}

getRoomNumber(): void {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        this.roomNumbers.push({label: i.toString(), value: i});
    }
}
```

after those dropdowns, I have an input field, which I need  to populate with the concat label of 1 + 2 dropdown.

Here is this input field

```
<div class="form-group"> 
                    <label>{{l("RoomName")}}</label>
                    <input #roomNameInput="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" name="roomName" [(ngModel)]="room.roomName"   maxlength="32">
                </div>
```

I tried to do this like this `(ngModelChange)="setRoomName(room.roomTypeId,room.roomNumber)"` on both dropdowns. But it just getting id of options.

How I can concat those labels, correctly?

Comment: Use: `(ngModelChange)="setRoomName(room)"` in ts: `setRoomName(room){this.room.roomName= room.roomTypeId + room.roomNumber }`?

Comment: It just get id of dropdowns. I need labels @PrashantPimpale

Comment: For example....?

Comment: For example now I get 6 + 2.

I room type is label: type1 and id: 6

I need to get label of selected option, not id @PrashantPimpale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use reactive form everything is much more clean and easy to understand. Using reactive form i will do something like this:

in template:

```
<form [formGroup]="roomForm">
  <select class="form-control" formControlName="roomType">
    <option *ngFor="let opt of types" [ngValue]="opt">{{ opt.label }}</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" formControlName="roomNumber">
    <option *ngFor="let opt of nums" [ngValue]="opt">{{ opt.label }}</option>
  </select>
  <input class="form-control" formControlName="inputString"/>
</form>
```

and in component:

```
export class Component   implements OnInit {
  nums  = [{label: 'label 1', value: 1 }, {label: 'label 2', value: 2}, {label: 'label 3', value: 3}];
  types = [{label: 'label a', value: 'a'}, {label: 'label b', value: 'b'}, {label: 'label c', value:'c'}];
  inputNum: string = '';
  inputType: string = '';
  subs: Subscription[] = [];

  roomForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.roomForm = new FormGroup({
      roomType: new FormControl(),
      roomNumber: new FormControl(),
      inputString: new FormControl()
    })
    this.subs.push(
      this.roomForm.get('roomType').valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
        this.inputType = val.label;
        this.roomForm.get('inputString').setValue(this.inputNum + this.inputType);
      })
    )

    this.subs.push(
      this.roomForm.get('roomNumber').valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
        this.inputNum = val.label;
        this.roomForm.get('inputString').setValue(this.inputNum.toString() + this.inputType);
      })
    )
  }
}
```

To use reactive form you have to import in your module ReactiveFormsModule.
Hope this can solve your problem!